# compile WRF-VPRM to have EBIO_GEE and EBIO_RES fluxes in your output

Tags: wrf-chem

I am working on WRF_GHG, I would like to run WRF-VPRM and I've put the vprm input files in WRF folder(vprm_input_d01_2010-01-16_00:00:00,vprm_input_d01_2010-01-17_00:00:00).but when I run wrf(./wrf.exe) ,I can't have *EBIO_GEE* and *EBIO_RES* fluxes in my wrf-output files.I think maybe I compiled the model wrong, that is the reason that I can't have two of these parameters in my wrf_output files.
can you help me, please?
Thank you very much indeed
best regards
Sara

Comment: I am running WRF-VPRM. I write 7 parameters related to VPRM into wrfinput. After running wrfout, CO2_BIO has changed. After adding a human source, CO2_ANT has also changed. But CO2_OCE has not changed. Do you know the reason for this? Is there a need for a marine emission inventory, and if so, how should it be given? Can you help me solve my doubts?